# Magento 2 : URGENT - Getting same product in resolver

Tags: magento2, graphql

I am using graphql mutation

```
mutation {
  addProductsToCart(
    cartId: "KlV2AfyAkbn19yuXE8EaBmabYqh4DMiX"
    cartItems: [{ quantity: 1, sku: "S359120" }]
  ) {
    cart {
      items {
        product {
          name
          sku
          custom_category {
            category
            doll_category
            special_category
          }
        }
        quantity
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see i pass "S359120" sku but in its resolver i get different sku.

```
<?php
    
    declare (strict_types = 1);
    
    namespace Vendor\ProductGraphQl\Model\Resolver;
    
    use Vendor\Segment\Helper\Tracking;
    use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
    use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;
    use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
    use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable;
    use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
    
    /**
     * Product attributes (product_category,special_category,doll_category) resolver, used for GraphQL request processing.
     */
    class ProductCustomCategoryResolver implements ResolverInterface
    {
         /**
         * @var Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable
         */
        private $configurableProduct;
    
        /**
         * @var Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
         */
        private $product;
    
        /**
         * @var Tracking
         */
        protected $segment_helper;
    
        /**
         * @param \DollsKill\Segment\Helper\Tracking $segment_helper
         */
        public function __construct(
            Tracking $segment_helper,
            Configurable $configurableProduct,
            Product $product
        )
        {
            $this->segment_helper = $segment_helper;
            $this->configurableProduct = $configurableProduct;
            $this->product             = $product;
        }
    
        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public function resolve(Field $field, $context, ResolveInfo $info, array $value = null, array $args = null)
        {
            $product = $value['model'];
            echo $product->getSku(); //getting same sku on every graphql mutation call
        }
    }
```

**app/code/Vendor/ProductGraphQl/etc/schema.graphqls**

```
interface ProductInterface {
    custom_category: [ProductCustomCategoryResolver] @doc(description: "Custom Product categories") @resolver(class: "\\DollsKill\\ProductGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\ProductCustomCategoryResolver")
}


type ProductCustomCategoryResolver {
    category: String
    doll_category: String
    special_category: String
}
```

Comment: please elaborate more

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment let me add more details

Comment: Please check now @Devidas

Comment: no  thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
<?php
    
    declare (strict_types = 1);
    
    namespace Vendor\ProductGraphQl\Model\Resolver;
    
    use Vendor\Segment\Helper\Tracking;
    use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
    use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;
    use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
    use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable;
    use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
    
    /**
     * Product attributes (product_category,special_category,doll_category) resolver, used for GraphQL request processing.
     */
    class ProductCustomCategoryResolver implements ResolverInterface
    {
         /**
         * @var Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable
         */
        private $configurableProduct;
    
        /**
         * @var Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
         */
        private $product;
    
        /**
         * @var Tracking
         */
        protected $segment_helper;
    
        /**
         * @param \Vendor\Segment\Helper\Tracking $segment_helper
         */
        public function __construct(
            Tracking $segment_helper,
            Configurable $configurableProduct,
            Product $product
        )
        {
            $this->segment_helper = $segment_helper;
            $this->configurableProduct = $configurableProduct;
            $this->product             = $product;
        }
    
        /**
         * @param Field $field
         * @param $context
         * @param ResolveInfo $info
         * @param array|null $value
         * @param array|null $args
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function resolve(Field $field, $context, ResolveInfo $info, array $value = null, array $args = null)
        {
            if (!array_key_exists('model', $value) || !$value['model'] instanceof ProductInterface) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('"model" value should be specified'));
            }
                $product = $value['model'];
                $data = $this->getData($product);
        }

        /**
         * @param ProductInterface $product
         * @return mixed
         */
        private function getData(ProductInterface $product)
        {
           echo $product->getSku();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but Its not working still getting some other sku